# rate of change for exam information

Tags: calculus

we are given following problem:
Students are given an exam and retake the exam later.  The average score on the exam is

```
 S = 80 - 14ln(t + 1)
```

where t is the number of months after the exam that the student retook the exam.  At what rate is the average student forgetting the information after 6 months?
i think  that we should take derivative of S with respect t and put 6 into derivative .in this case
`dS/dt=-14/(t+1)` if we put t=6 we get  -(14/7)=-2 so it means that about 2 student forget information after 6 month?am i right ?maybe i am confused of some condition of this problem if so please help.

Comment: aaa  yes it is clear i have mixed in each other  thanks @anon

Comment: @Andre: Oh yes, please excuse my brain for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The calculation is correct.  The conclusion about "$2$ students" is not.

The *rate of change* of the mark at time $t=6$ (months) is indeed $-2$.

In informal language, we can conclude that the mark at $t=6$ is decreasing at the rate of $2$ marks a month.  (Increasing at rate $-2$ would sound funny to most people, but is certainly correct.)

The conclusion should not mention anything that involves the number of *students*.